# show or read all files and folder present in os or system using electron

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron

I am new to electron and I wanted to develop a file explorer (cross platform application for desktop) using electron.

I am unable to read root folder.

How can i read root folder in windows, Linux and mac ?

I tried the following code but it resulted in an error:

```
const fs = require('fs');
const fileUrl = new URL('file:///Desktop');
fs.readFileSync(fileUrl);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want to read all files in a directory you should use another function in fs called fs.readdir or fs.readdirSync

```js
// Callback
fs.readdir('/home/guest/projects', (err, files) => {
    console.log(files);
})
// Sync
fs.readdirSync('/home/guest/projects')
```